# How to get path of a file in local machine from webapplication

Tags: java

I'm trying to upload a excel file from an application and trying to store the data in db and it is perfectly working in my system. But when im trying it from other machine I'm getting Error like path not found.

The reason for that error is known. it's because the file path is belongs to the other system and the server(tomcat) is in my system. when I passed that path as parameter server is searching in my system.

So here my question how to access the file from that system.?

Comment: keep a config to store files in specific locaton like {user.dir}/resources

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to take the path from the network you are related in :

```
    File FileToRead = new File(new URI("file://MYSERVER/MYFOLDER/MYFOLDER/MYPICTURE.JPG"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're passing your server a path on your machine. Since your server also runs on your machine it will find the file on your hard drive. However, when a user from another machine passes a path, your server will still try to look on your machine (since this is where it runs).

Your server will not be able to read the file on another machine (unless you have some file sharing stuff going on your local network).

You'll need to add upload functionality to your server which can receive the actual file (not just the path to the file).

Comment: I got the solution by adding enctype="multipart/form-data"

<form id="LoadFormId" name="LoadForm" theme="simple" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="myaction.do">